# Is it possible to apply a mask on an image using jquery/javascript/html5?

Tags: php, jquery, image

I am looking for a way to cat a part of an image, using another image as a mask.

I don't know if this is at all possible using web technologies. I am willing of using libraries (jquery, php, javascript) or anything available on the market that does just that.

In general, I want to create themes that use resources that I don't have to cut in order to make them in different shapes (rectangles, circles etc). I onlywant to be able to apply a mask to them on the fly.

I am aware of `ImageMagick®` but cant figure out a way on how to use it to have such results without making my code ugly.

If you don't have a clue on what masking is, here's a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).

Comment: Webkit surely can do this:
http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/
Mozilla says:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-webkit-mask-image
"Note that since version 1.9.1 Gecko supports SVG filter effects, which you can use to apply masks to HTML content."

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Thank you! Can this be done in non-gecko browsers also?

Comment: Well, IE has (had) filters, and there are some js solutions like
http://www.netzgesta.de/edge/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you're talking about juxtaposing images. If so, you can encapsulate a div into another, like this:

```
<div id="div1">
 <div id="<div2">
 </div>
</div>
```

And then put your image as a CSS background for div2 and the mask for div1.

Comment: Masks are used to subtract parts of an image. This will result in "transparent" color in the subtracted areas. I believe what you say is irrelevant.

Comment: @odyodyodys It can be used when you have a color background (without image), you assign the overhead image the same color that your background has and it will seems to be a mask.